# Explain the behavior of "max" in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby, and want to understand the following piece of code.

When I have a array with strings, and operate it with the max function:

```
names = ["aa", "bb", "cc"]
names.max = "cc"
```

and if I have a hash here,

```
calendar["January", :cold, "February", :colder] 
calendar.max = ["January", :cold]
```

I am not able to understand whether it is the longest word size or the member with the largest index size that is being displayed. Could anyone explain the behavior? Am I missing something very basic?

Comment: That's a strange hash you have there. Are you sure it's a hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are sorted by comparing elements at corresponding positions. Strings are sorted lexicographically. `"J"` is "greater" then `"F"`, thus, `["January", :cold]` is greater than `["February", :colder]`, regardless of string length and remaining array elements.

```
months = %w[january february march april may june july august september october november december]

months.sort.join(', ') # => "april, august, december, february, january, july, june, march, may, november, october, september"
```